# get the sequenced reads present 300 base near to restriction sites

Tags: python, r, perl

I have many sam file containing sequenced reads and i want to get the reads which are present near to restriction sequence at least 300 bases in both direction.
1st File containing the position of restrion sites, having two columns.
chr01 4957
chr01 6605
chr02 19968
chr02 21055
chr02 208555
chr03 243398

2nd file having the reads in SAM file format. (almost 2.6M lines)

id1995    147     chr03   119509969       42      85M
id1999    83      chr10   131560619       26      81M
id1999    163     chr10   131560429       26      85M
id2099    73      chr10   60627850        42      81M

Now I want to compare column 3 of sam file with column one of position file and column 4 of sam file with column 2 of position file. 
I tried doing in R language but because the data is large it is taking lot of time to do.
if you can improve the R script to do work faster by implementing best algorithm.
R code:

```
pos = read.csv(file="sites.csv",header=F,sep="\t")
fastq = read.csv(file="reads.sam", header=F,sep="\t")
newFastq = data.frame(fastq)
newFastq = NULL
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

for(i  in 1:nrow(fastq)){
for(j in 1:nrow(pos)){
    if(as.character(fastq[i,3]) == trim(as.character(pos[j,1]))){
      if(fastq[i,4] - pos[j,2] < 300 && fastq[i,4] - pos[j,2] > -300){
       newFastq = rbind(newFastq,fastq[i,])
     }
   }
 }  
}
#Write data into file 
write.table(newFastq, file = "sitesFound.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="",quote=FALSE,col.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

or can you improve this code by writing in perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One overall strategy is to make indexed bam files using [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org) [Rsamtools](https://bioconductor.org/packages/Rsamtools) `asBam()` and `indexBam()`. Read your first file into a data.frame and construct a [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/GenomicRanges) `GRanges()` object. Finally, use [GenomicAlignments](https://bioconductor.org/packages/GenomicAlignments) `readGAlignments()` to read the bam file, using the `GRanges()` as the which= argument to `ScanBamParam()`. The Bioconductor support site https://support.bioconductor.org is more appropriate for Bioconductor questions, if you decide to go this route.

It looks like you want reads that are within +/- 300 base pairs of your GRanges object. Resize the GRanges

```
library(GenomicRanges)
## create gr = GRanges(...)
gr = resize(gr, width = 600, fix="center")
```

use this as the `which=` in `ScanBamParam()`, and read your BAM file

```
library(GenomicAlignments)
param = ScanBamParam(which = gr)
reads = readGAlignments("your.bam", param = param)
```

Use `what=` to control fields read from the BAM file, e.g.

```
param = ScanBamParam(which = gr, what = "seq")
```

Comment: the use bioconductor for this problem look relevant if its able to compare the location between two file faste than the code i have written .

Comment: generally it will be 'fast'; there will be no R-level iteration (no `for` loop) in your final solution.

Comment: can you provide the possible script by which i can compare the two files using Rsamtools and GRanges()

Comment: Have you created the BAM files from your SAM files, and created the GRanges object from your 'sites.csv' file?

Comment: yes i have created BAM file and GRanges object. Next process script please.

Comment: many thanks for helping out in this. Now the R giving error while running readGAlignments () .   > reads = readGAlignments("sample1_sort.bam", param = param)
Error in .io_bam(.scan_bamfile, file, reverseComplement, yieldSize(file),  : 
  seqlevels(param) not in BAM header:

Comment: Looks like you're also asking [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/104827/) which is the more appropriate place, so let's continue on https://support.bioconductor.org